# php can't delete cookie

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have this function to set a cookie:

```
private function setCookie($key, $value){
        if(setcookie(
            $key,
            $this->encrypt($value),
            time() + 2592000,
            adminpath,
            database::getDomain(),
            database::getHTTPS(),
            true
        )){ // set cookie for a month
            return true;
        }
        else{ // cookie could not be created, write to errorlog
             $error  = array(
                "type"      => "other",
                "argument"  => 1,
                "class"     => __CLASS__,
                "function"  => __FUNCTION__,
                "errorMsg"  => "Could not create cookie ".$key." with value ".$value,
                "file"      => __FILE__,
                "line"      => __LINE__
            );
            $this->errorlog->log($error);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Then I use this code to unset the cookie:

```
private function destroyCookie($key){
        if(setcookie(
            $key,
            " ",
            time() - (time() + 2592000), 
            adminpath,
            database::getDomain(),
            database::getHTTPS(),
            true
        )){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            $error  = array(
                "type"      => "other",
                "argument"  => 1,
                "class"     => __CLASS__,
                "function"  => __FUNCTION__,
                "errorMsg"  => "Could not destroy cookie ".$key,
                "file"      => __FILE__,
                "line"      => __LINE__
            );
            $this->errorlog->log($error);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I'm probably missing something very simple, but I can't figure out why my cookie isn't deleted.
Both functions are in the same class and the function database::getDomain() results in "www.creetab.com" and the function database::getHTTPS() results in "false". adminpath is "/admin/".
Could someone please help me fix this problem?
Setting the cookie works fine, it's just deleting the cookie that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$key,
" ",
time() - (time() + 2592000),
```

should be:

```
$key,
"",
time() - 2592000,
```

Otherwise you are just giving it a value of an empty space, which is still a value. You want to give it no value at all, by making it empty. Also set the expiration time as above.